# Is the following sentence well written?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure if I should write 'is' instead of 'are'

The following **are** the email address and password

The following **is** the email address and password

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Questions about English grammar belong on English SE. Please see our help center for the kinds of questions which are on-topic for us, http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and I will ask the mods to migrate.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is not well written either way. It is unnecessarily convoluted. All you need to say is "The email address and password are:" But since they are two distinct pieces of information, it would be simpler still to say, "The email address is "foo@example.com" and the password is "bananas". This would remove all ambiguity of number.

And I think this is a good rule of thumb for all situations where plural vs singular is unclear: rewrite the sentence so that it is clear.

Comment: This is the only complete answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's break into the sentence and tear it apart.

Start by counting the pieces of information presented:

1. Email address
2. Password

When introducing two or more objects, use a plural verb. It's actually quite simple. You have it right when you can switch around the order without changing the words. "The email address and password are following." "Supplied are the following: the email address, and the password."

It may help to use another two-piece example: "Here are my grandma and grandpa." To be sure you can turn it around: "My grandma and grandpa are here!" (It's actually true.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the point of the question was not how to rephrase the sentences, but the proper use of the words.

Since you are referring to multiple items (the email address and the password) the proper word to use is '***are***'.

For example.  'My hat and gloves ***are*** on the desk.'  NOT 'my hat and gloves ***is*** on the desk'